# Pipe column names to assertive

Tags: r, magrittr

I am trying to use the `assertive` package for run-time testing, and I would like to pass column names using the pipe.

Here's a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(assertive)
df <- tibble(Name = c("DONALD", "JAIME", "LINDA"))
```

This works but doesn't use the pipe:

```
assertive::assert_all_are_true(df$Name == str_to_upper(df$Name))
```

This uses the pipe, but doesn't work:

```
df %>% assertive::assert_all_are_true(Name == str_to_upper(Name))
#> Error in match.arg(severity): object 'Name' not found
```

How can I pipe column names to `assertive`?

Comment: If you're loading magrittr explcitly, try `df %$% assertive::assert_all_are_true(Name == str_to_upper(Name))` rather than using `%>%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `with`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     with(., assertive::assert_all_are_true(Name == str_to_upper(Name)))
```

---

Or extract the column with `.$`

```
df %>%
    {assertive::assert_all_are_true(.$Name == str_to_upper(.$Name))}
```

---

Or with `|>` from `R 4.1.0`

```
df |> 
    {\(x) assertive::assert_all_are_true(x$Name == str_to_upper(x$Name))}()
```